# Missed typo in first-post review

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

So I just failed a review audit for this [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5186889), and handed a review ban. Apparently my Java is a bit rusty and I missed the same single character typo the OP did.  Now it's not a great question, but it had the code and the specific the error, which is more than you tend to get with these type of first posts.

Now without the context of votes and comments, I think the typo is an easy thing to miss.

Was this really a fair review worthy of a review ban?

Comment: You don't get review banned for one audit failure. Are you sure you haven't failed any other audits recently?

Comment: I did have another failure four days ago with a 2 day review ban. But that one didn't strike me as unfair at the time, so I didn't raise issue.  This one seems borderline to me.

Comment: `my Java is a bit rusty`: that shouldn't even matter in this case. You were reviewing First Posts, which is a queue that is crucial to the overall quality of the site because it gives us a chance to correct the behavior of new users and (if they care enough) to help them improve. Just looking at that post should tell you that it's not a high-quality question in any way, and **No Action Needed** is not an appropriate review. There are content and grammar issues and it is 95% code. Those are the kinds of things that new users need to be informed about: that's your responsibility in First Posts.

Answer (score 3):

> Apparently my Java is a bit rusty and I missed the same simple typo the OP did

Unfortunately, this is why you were banned and I don't think a ban should be reversed because of this.

First, [as you have said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262067/missed-typo-in-first-post-review#comment50530_262067), this is not your first failed audit and not your first review ban.  To be banned the first time, you obviously failed multiple audits to lead to the original ban, so you have a history of failed audits.

Secondly, you should not be reviewing a post unless you are 100% confident your decision is correct.  If you aren't comfortable with the material and you choose to review it then you are being unfair to the OP.  This is especially true in First Posts and Late Answers.  In these review queues, posts are only reviewed by **1 person**, so if you can't be certain you are reviewing fairly then you aren't performing a complete review and the OP could be missing valuable feedback on the post (be it comments, votes, or edits).